# Function with $f(0)=1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$

Tags: calculus, functions

I don't think there's any other approach except guessing. I thought of

$$f(x)=e^{-2x} ; x\geq0$$

$$e^{2x} ; x<0$$

But this is basically two different functions. Is there a function with a single formula satisfying $f(0)=1$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$? I think the graph should look like this:[image]

Has anyone seen this function?

EDIT: There's two more conditions: The value of the function should drop faster than or at least the same rate as $e^{−2|x|}$ on both sides of $x=0$. And the function should keep decreasing on both sides of $x=0$. So, the function should keep decreasing on both sides of $x=0$ and the decreasing rate should be faster or at least equal to the exponential decrease rate.

Comment: How about $f(x)=1$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere?

Comment: Perhaps you want something continuous everywhere?

Comment: Your function is $f(x)= e^{-2|x|}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cosh (\pi x)}$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp But that's the same function I've written. Yes, in your case it is a single formula but I want something I don't need to split while integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp That's still two formulae. And yes, I want something continuous.

Comment: @RandomVariable That should do. But one more thing, I want a function whose value drops faster than or at least the same rate as $e^{-2|x|}$ on either side of $x=0$. Does your function satisfy that? And, I'm not familiar with hyperbolic functions. Is your function periodic? My function should keep decreasing on both sides of $x=0$.

Comment: $Ce^{-x^2}$, for appropriate $C$.

Comment: @Dove: Your function is continuous. BTW, a periodic function could never satisfy what you want. If you want fast decay, go with Gerry's suggestion.

Comment: It doesn't immediately decay faster than $e^{-2|x|}$. But since $\frac{1}{\cosh (\pi x)} = \frac{2}{e^{\pi x} + e^{- \pi x}}$, it eventually starts decaying like $2 e^{-\pi |x|}$.

Comment: Not "$Ce^{-x^2}$ for appropriate $C$" because $C$ must be $1$ for $f(0)$ to be $1$, and then the total integral won't be $1$. Instead, $e^{-(kx)^2}$ for appropriate $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here it is in answer form. (Such a strange policy...)

One option would be the Gaussian distribution $G(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$. Because of the way $\sigma$ scales $G(x)$ in the $x$ direction without changing the area, you can just let $s= G(x=0, \sigma=1, \mu=0)$ and $f(x)=G(x, \sigma=s, \mu=0)$. Keep in mind though that there isn't a closed-form way to integrate $G$ over finite bounds, but that shouldn't be a problem if you only care about $\pm\infty$.

This is how you'd get the $C$ in what @gerry-myerson suggested.

Comment: Actually, as @alex points out in the comments, my own comment was not correct, in terms of what one needs to adjust.

Comment: How is this different from my hint which was posted 4 hours earlier??

Comment: Yourself, @rb612, and I all end up suggesting the same function. I'd left the page open without refreshing, so I didn't see your answer until after I posted.

I guess there is a slight difference in our answers. rb612 and I give a way to construct the particular Gaussian distribution that meets the requirements, while yours gives it outright.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - it comes from normal distribution function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{|a|\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(\frac{x}{a})^2}$$

This has the property that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\ dx = 1$.

You want $f(0) = 1$. Thus, $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$$f(x) = \frac{1}{|a|\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(\frac{x}{a})^2}$$

So you arrive at:

$$f(x) = e^{-(x\sqrt{\pi})^2} = e^{-\pi x^2}$$

Comment: The "normal distribution" is not as you've written it twice.  You need a minus sign in the exponent!

Comment: @MarkViola oh no! I don’t know how I missed that - I had it in the answer but not in the immediate steps. Just fixed. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

What is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx$?

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\int_0^∞ \dfrac{dx}{1 + a x^2} = \dfrac{π}{2 \sqrt{a}}
$,
setting
$a = \pi^2$ gives
$\int_0^∞ \dfrac{dx}{1 + \pi^2 x^2} = \dfrac12
$
so
$\int_{-∞}^∞ \dfrac{dx}{1 + \pi^2 x^2} 
=1
$.

Comment: But this doesn't decay faster than exponential.

Comment: I think that was added in an edit about the same time I entered my answer.